# Multieffect pedals- Do companies pay royalties to original pedal makers?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, music

When looking into effects list of multieffect pedals (ex: Boss Gt6, Zoom ms50g...), the manual clearly identifies the effects of whom the original pedals where modeled from. And recent multieffect pedals with there modern audio processors are able to highly imitate the original effects(amps, drive, reverb, delay).

Do these companies pay royalties to the original manufacturers when they include copied sounds from them? If I buy multieffects due to their practicality in size and cost, am I supporting the original pedal/amp makers who have been manufacturing for years and deserve credit for the signature sound they made?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about some individual private contracts, not general or public principles of law.

Comment: @Nij Lol. I posted this question on Music Exchange, they closed it as off topic and sent me here. What do I do, open a new Exchange for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Do these companies pay royalties to the original manufacturers when they include copied sounds from them?*

It's possible; you would have to examine each companies' licensing agreement with the original developers and manufacturer of the effects pedals, and look at the patents for each original device.

Such pedals can be patented, i.e: https://www.google.com/patents/US7476799 . You can search for patents for each of those devices.

Patents can be licensed to manufacturers and other companies while the patent is in term. Patents also (generally) expire after 20 years [Term of patent - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent), so compnaies can make their own pedals using the original inventions.

> *If I buy multieffects due to their practicality in size and cost, am I supporting the original pedal/amp makers who have been manufacturing
>   for years and deserve credit for the signature sound they made?*

Again, unless someone else with direct knowledge of the legal agreements and patents adds an anseer, or you do in-depth research, it's a guess. But it's fair to say some patents have expired, and companies can combine and make their own pedals with no threat of legal action for patent or IP infringement.